# Is there a model of set theory in which $\mathfrak p< \mathfrak b < \mathfrak q$?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, infinite-combinatorics, cardinal-characteristics

Is there a model of set theory in which $\mathfrak p< \mathfrak b < \mathfrak q$?

Here $\mathfrak p$, $\mathfrak b$, $\mathfrak q$ are [small uncountable cardinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_characteristic_of_the_continuum):

- $\mathfrak p$ is the smallest cardinality of any family $\mathcal F \subseteq [\omega]^\omega$, which has the strong finite intersection property, but does not have a pseudo intersection;
- $\mathfrak b$ is the bounding number;
- $\mathfrak q = \min\{\kappa :\text{ no subset }X \subseteq \mathbb R\text{ of cardinality }|X| \ge κ\text{ is a Q-set}\}$.

  - $\min\{\mathfrak b, \mathfrak q \}\in \{\mathfrak p,\mathfrak q \}$ ?

Comment: Probably you should clarify a bit what you mean by p, b and q. Although a reasonable guess would be that you mean [small uncountable cardinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_characteristic_of_the_continuum). I.e., $\mathfrak p$ is the smallest cardinality of system which has s.f.i.p. but now infinite pseudointersection. (Do some people call this power number?) And $\mathfrak b$ is bounding number. I am not sure about $\mathfrak q$.

Comment: p is the smallest cardinality of system which has s.f.i.p. but now infinite pseudointersection. b is bounding number. q = min{κ : no subset X ⊂ R of cardinality |X| ≥ κ is a Q-set}.

Comment: @Alexander Could you put it in the body text?

Comment: @AlexanderOsipov I have added at least this basic information into the text. If you have something more that could be useful for readers of your question, please do edit it further.

Comment: I have seen $\mathfrak{q}$ be defined as the minimal size of a set of reals which is not a Q-set. Is this definition equivalent to the one given in the question?

Comment: If  $\mathfrak{q}_0 = \min\{|X| : X\subset \mathbb{R}$, $X$ is not a Q-set$\}$,  then $\mathfrak{q}_0\leq \mathfrak{q}$. There is a model of set theory  $\mathfrak{q}_0< \mathfrak{q}$. (Banakh, Taras; Machura, Michal; Zdomskyy, L. On critical cardinalities related to Q-sets, Mathematical Bulletin of the Shevchenko Scientific Society 11 (2014), 21--32.)